# How to check on inserting new values if they already exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource to bind data to gridview.

- I have 3 columns in database : Name,Age,Birthday.
- I have 3 textboxes and a button for adding new row with values from
  textboxes in the data table , gridview.

When I click the button for adding a new row with those information , I need to check if the value from textbox for "Name" already exists in the data table in the column "Name" if yes then the update is canceled and the user is asked to enter another value.

Comment: Need more information, do you need to check the database and see if the value exists before inserting it?  What column are you checking?  We are not mind readers on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry for this , take a look again at my question please . updated

Comment: A properly designed database will already take care of this for you.  The name field you are telling us should be UNIQUE.  If its unique (possibly the primary key is the name field) the db system will scream at you if you re-insert a record that exists.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off defining a Unique Index on the column name in the table. You can let the code execute w/o checking whether the name exists or not. It will come back with an error if the name already exists (which you can capture and display nicely to the user); and succeed if the name does not exist in the table.

I don't know which database you use, but something like this should work on most databases.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON your_table (name)
```

Comment: I'm using Sql Database , may I ask what should I do with your code? thank you.

Comment: @Alexander execute the than SQL statement on your database directly. Connect to your database with SQL Server Management Studio or with Visual Studio directly.

Comment: Execute the statment each time when adding a new row or?..sorry I've never heard about that and never used. thank you

Comment: No, I am talking about creating an index on a table. I am not telling you to execute that statement every time a row is inserted. And more so when we are talking about creating an index. You need to read up on databases and specially indexes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Comment: yes I've already have a database index column . ( primary key , auto increment by 1 , seed by 1 )

Comment: You need to add another one, this time for the name column.

Comment: I can't set primary key to the colum Name, I can only set 1 primary / table

Comment: A Unique Index is not a Primary Key. I am telling you to create a **unique index** http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/difference-between-an-index-and-a-primary-key/

Comment: Alexander open up sql management studio, create a new query window.  Then select your database at the top.  Copy and paste what icarus posted but replace it with your table name.

Comment: Ok I will do that , btw: I found how to make a contrait but I don't know what code for expression should I write to make a colum unique

Comment: @Alexander a constraint will also work but I have the feeling that you'll be querying the table by name quite constantly, which is why I recommend the index instead.

Comment: okay new query window , I replaced the query : Select from table name with CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Name
ON mytable and I get error saying it can't be represented

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution based on how I'm understanding your question would be to run a quick query before doing an insert.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblName WHERE Name = @Name
```

And, if the value is zero, you have nothing in your database matching that name. Alternatively, if you want to find the ID of the matching name when selecting, you'd probably want to set up a stored procedure. Have a return value that initially queries for matching names, and: IF (@ReturnValue is null), perform the insert and return the value with

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```